# Type of React components for arrays

Tags: reactjs, typescript

We usually use `React.FC<Props>` as return type of the react functional component

For the following component

```
const MyComponent = ({myArray}) => {
    return myArray.map(
        (item, index) => <span key={index} className='foo'>{item}</span>
    );
}
```

if we wrap the returned value with `Fragment` we can use `React.FC<Props>` but without `Fragment` how can I prevent errors like `Initializer type ({myArray}: {myArray: any}) => any is not assignable to variable type React.FC<Props>`

Comment: I think your method signature should look more like `const MyComponent = ({myArray}:{myArray:any[]}) => {` or in place of `any` your actual item type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no pretty solution for this yet.
It's an open issue in [Typescript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21699)

There are two workarounds:

1. Wrap the array with fragment:

   ```
   <>
     {myArray.map(
       (item, index) => <span key={index} className='foo'>{item}</span>
     )}
   </>
   ```
2. cast the JSX Elements array to any type:

   ```
   myArray.map(
     (item, index) => <span key={index} className='foo'>{item}</span>
   ) as any
   ```

Reference from DefinitelyTyped: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/20356

Comment: Yep, wrap in fragments. @WebMaster